# How can you see the previous name of a renamed file in shell?

Tags: linux

I want to write a shell script to monitor changes (rename and delete) in files in a directory.

Comment: Then you should write it! Come back when you've tried. This might help http://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes

Comment: You really should edit your question to motivate it and explain why you want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should learn how to use a [revision control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) system, a.k.a. version control system. I strongly recommend using [git](http://git-scm.com/); I'm guessing that you need a VCS....

You may want to use Linux-specific [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities, e.g. with [incrontab(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/incrontab) files for [icrond(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/incrond) 
<sup>(it might not work well for network file systems like NFS; it is working better on Linux local file systems like Ext4 or BTRFS or XFS)</sup>